# What does "terms" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

> how likely are you to renew your relationship with us beyond the
>   current terms?

Does "terms" mean period or condition? Since there is "beyond" in this sentence, it could mean period, but I am not sure because usually "terms" mean condition.

Comment: It's not  clear to me, as a native English speaker. I _think_ it is a mistake for _beyond the current term_ (meaning 'period'), probably influenced by the prevalence of the word _terms_ in this sort of context.